# Why does my Spark app only use one of two workers in my cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector, apache-spark-standalone

I use standalone cluster with 2 workers.
Use spark kafka cassandra hdfs stream

```
val stream = kafkaUtils.createDirectStream...
stream.map(rec => Row(rec.offset, rev.value)).saveToCassandra(...)
stream.map(_.value).foreachRDD(rdd => {saving to HDFS})
```

I send to Kafka approximately 40000 msg/sec
the first thing that is saveToCassandra works slowly, because if i comment `stream.saveToCassandra` it works very good and fast.
in spark driver UI i see that for 5MB output it takes approximately 20s.
I tried to tune spark-cassandra options, but it also takes minimum 14s.

And the second is than i mentioned, that my one worker is do nothing, it log i see something like this:

```
10:05:33 INFO remove RDD#
```

and etc.

but if i stop another worker it begin to work.

I don't use spark-submit, just

`startSpark extends App {`

and the hole code, and then start it with

```
scala -cp "spark libs:kafka:startSpark.jar" startSpark
```

and in conf to workers i use `ssc.sparkContext.addJars(pathToNeedableJars)`

How can i boost writing to Cassandra and how to get my workers work together?

Comment: Also used it through spark-shell --master spark://192.168.1.40:7077 and :paste mode. And result is also as it was before, one node do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really bad reading official spark kafka integration guide, the problem, that i use for my topic 1 partition

> 1:1 correspondence between Kafka partitions and Spark partitions

Comment: Spark 2.1.1, kafka 0.10.2.1